# How to vlookup each comma separated value from range?

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have one data sheet with codes as csv
Other reference data sheet with each code and name it corresponds to.

How do I vlookup multiple items and return corresponding names
Cell B2 is where I want to vlookup and get Test,Abc

[image]

[image]

Comment: what version do you have?

Comment: If you do not have TEXTJOIN as a formula option this will require vba.

Comment: Office Pro+ 2016

Comment: You will need vba.

Comment: Can you show where the Names "Test" and "Abc" would be in the first screenshot?  Would they also be comma separated in B2?  Or...?

Comment: Yes. B2 is where I am trying to get Test,Abc. Reference data is on different tab. I just added them to column D,E in same tab for question purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If one has TEXTJOIN use:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IFERROR(VLOOKUP(FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(A2,",","</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b"),D:E,2,FALSE),""))
```

Depending on one's version this may need to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

If one does not have text join, put this code in a module attached to the workbook.

```
Function TEXTJOIN(delim As String, skipblank As Boolean, arr)
    Dim d As Long
    Dim c As Long
    Dim arr2()
    Dim t As Long, y As Long
    t = -1
    y = -1
    If TypeName(arr) = "Range" Then
        arr2 = arr.Value
    Else
        arr2 = arr
    End If
    On Error Resume Next
    t = UBound(arr2, 2)
    y = UBound(arr2, 1)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If t >= 0 And y >= 0 Then
        For c = LBound(arr2, 1) To UBound(arr2, 1)
            For d = LBound(arr2, 1) To UBound(arr2, 2)
                If arr2(c, d) <> "" Or Not skipblank Then
                    TEXTJOIN = TEXTJOIN & arr2(c, d) & delim
                End If
            Next d
        Next c
    Else
        For c = LBound(arr2) To UBound(arr2)
            If arr2(c) <> "" Or Not skipblank Then
                TEXTJOIN = TEXTJOIN & arr2(c) & delim
            End If
        Next c
    End If
    TEXTJOIN = Left(TEXTJOIN, Len(TEXTJOIN) - Len(delim))
End Function
```

Then use the formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,LOOKUP(FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(A2,",","</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b"),D:D,E:E))
```

using Ctrl-Shift-Enter to confirm.  Also make sure the lookup table is sorted ascending on the lookup column.

[image]

Comment: Apparently Excel 2016 Pro + doesn't have this unless you have office 365. I tried in Office with no luck. What are <a><b> for? Do they need to change if my data is column K and I am trying to get values in column L next to it?

Comment: Which is why I provided the vba code to mimic the TEXTJOIN function.  Put that code in a module attached to the workbook and you can then use the TEXTJOIN function.

Comment: Looks like FILTERXML is not available for web so that might be it.I will go VBA route thanks

Comment: Can you share the vba excel somewhere?

Comment: `VBA didnt work for me` is a little broad.  What specifically happened when you used it?

Comment: Also vba will not work with Excel online.  It will only work on the desktop version.

Comment: Edited question to add images

Comment: Did you use Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when confirming the formula?

Comment: Yes. Takes me to debug window. Fails at "Else
        arr2 = arr"

Comment: yeah, not sure why it is seeing it as a range.

Comment: See edit, had to break out my 2016 version to trouble shoot.  the problem was the formula not the vba.